# How to get phonemes of voice file using Praat

Tags: speech-recognition, praat

I want to get the phonemes of a voice. For this I was suggested to use Praat. http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/

Is this possible to be done using Praat? How should I approach this?

I have already done converting voice to text in real time. What I need is to move the lips of a robot according to the voice of another person speaking from another place. For this I need the phonemes or visemes of the voice. (I don't want convert voice to text and then to phonemes). I need Voice to Phonemes.

Or is there any other better tool available to do this?

Comment: It is not possible with Praat. Try something like https://github.com/DanielSWolf/rhubarb-lip-sync instead.

Comment: lip sync is done by a .NET program. I just want to get the phonemes of a voice in real time.

Comment: Try Festival or this program based on Festival https://github.com/bootphon/phonemizer